# Message: Attribute name "android:" associated with an element type "RelativeLayout" must be followed by the ' = ' character

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile

How to fix this error?

[image]

This error come when I am building a new project only.

> Message: Attribute name "android:" associated with an element type
> "RelativeLayout" must be followed by the ' = ' character.

Comment: Java is NOT THE SAME as JavaScript. Also do not include images of your errors, but paste it as a text. Also include your code.

Comment: Post the XML code where the error is, otherwise no one can tell